# Can you have a conditional in the htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Been looking around the web to add a production rule in the `.htaccess` file. I have a wordpress website; one for production and the other, staging.

When a file is uploaded, it goes to AWS (s3). I need to prevent this behaviour for staging.

The code that sets the asset path is, in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/<BUCKET-NAME>/wp-content/uploads/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I cant seem to find an "if statement" or some sort of condition to use. Honestly, I think this is not possible. Is it?

I only need to run that code for production and not staging. **Staging url is different from production**.

**Updated**

Whenever I use below, my website crashes:

```
<If "-z req('Host') == 'www.<PRODUCTION>.com/'">
  RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/<BUCKET-NAME>/wp-content/uploads/$1 [R=301,L]
</If>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`If` directive works on Apache 2.4 and newer versions. On lower versions you can use `RewriteCond` directive to conditionally rewrite urls.

You can use something like this

```
RewriteEngine on
#if host == "www.production.com"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.production.com$ [NC]
 # execute the rule
 RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ https: //s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/<BUCKET-NAME>/wp-content/uploads/$1 [R=301,L]
```